# How to assign int value to integer variable

Tags: java, android, integer, int

How can I convert an int value to integer value?

Here is my code-

```
private static int[] value= {R.drawable.collection1,R.drawable.collection2}

public static ArrayList<Integer> AddIntValue (int[] value){
    ArrayList<Integer> Intvalue=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0;i<value.length; i++)
    {
        Intvalue.add(Integer.valueOf(value[i]), null);
    }

    return Intvalue;
}
```

Am getting error on **Intvalue.add(Integer.valueOf(value[i]), null);**

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: You arraylist is empty, so adding at a specific position (which does not exist yet) will throw an exception. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No.I tryed Integer k=Integer.valueOf(value[i]);  before Intvalue.add(Integer.valueOf(value[i]), null);  then i found that K is not null k have value.

Comment: looking at one of your previous comments, you seem to mix `R.integer` and `Integer`. You should clarify what you want (in other words, what do you want the list to contain after that method).

Answer (score 5):

java 5 added autoboxing, so you should just be able to use this

```
int i=3;
Integer number=i;//number now equals 3
```

The reason you are getting an error is because you are using the array for indices and trying to add null at this indices.  If you array was {100,101,102}, It would try to add null to intValues at index 100, 101, and 102, which don't exist, giving you the IndexOutOfBoundsEception;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your code and still has control over elements list index, you have to:
1. Initzialize ArrayList size
2. Use correctly add method

```
public static List<Integer> addIntValue(int[] value) {
    List<Integer> intValues = new ArrayList<Integer>(value.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        intValues.add(i, value[i]);
    }

    return intValues;
}
```